# Can coupon code entered stay in step without refreshing page/going to cart?

Tags: checkout, onepage-checkout, coupon-codes

Currently I have a working Coupon code section on the last step of my onepage checkout, but whenever entering a code, it reverts back to the cart page and applies the code.. but if its something like free shipping.. it will show the free shipping on the cart page, but then you are going through the checkout again and having to select a shipping option, thus removing the free shipping effect again.

I imagine the code that is bringing it back to the cart page is

```
<form id="discount-coupon-form" action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/cart/couponPost') ?>" method="post">
```

Namely, the 'checkout/cart/couponPost' action.

Is there anyway possible for the user to get to the review step, enter the code, and just possibly refresh that specific step? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you change it to

```
<form id="discount-coupon-form" action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/onepage/coupon/') ?>" method="post">
```

does it work?

Comment: Thanks for commenting! That actually sent it back to the homepage. That could have something to do with any 404 page is directed to the homepage, but as far as staying on the checkout/last step, it didn't work unfortunately.